# What chart tool should I use to create charts in php?

Tags: php, jquery, flash

I am creating a charts report in php but not understanding what should I use.

Can you help me, what chart tool should I use?

Comment: If you really generate a chart in PHP, the best you canr eally do is a static image. For Interactive charts, you really need to generate the chart in javascript with data provided by PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sort of charts are you looking forward to work with ? Opensource ? or the other way? 
For a licensed Version, you can take a look at this [Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) (Flash and javascript). 
[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). (demos and trial versions are also available.)
 For opensource take a look at the [Google chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/). Google provides you with both static and interactive charts.
 Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

jpgraph has been around for a while

rgraph seems capable as well.

EDIT://

http://www.rgraph.net/

http://jpgraph.net/

Comment: Links would be helpful, especially on such a short answer

Comment: and there they are, on a silver plate...

Answer (score 1):

You can try these.

1. [pCharts](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/)
2. [jpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/)
3. [Google Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/) (JQuery)
4. [XML/SWF charts](http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/index.php?menu=Gallery&submenu=3D_Pie) (3D)

Comment: Thanks for everyone replies.
I have used all suggested chart tools apart from these i have tried fusionchart.Drill down feature is amazing of the fusion chart.
I think we can easily manage all parameters of chart using fusion chart.

Answer (score 1):

Is this for a web application? If so, consider rendering the charts client-side using JavaScript.

I use [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[pChart 2](http://www.pchart.net/) is great, free and easy to use. Unfortunately it is released under the GPLv3, so you cannot use it for a commercial product (but I think you can buy a license).

Answer (score 0):

heyy 
lot of chart apis available some of them are listed.
1.jpgraph
2.Koolgraph
3.jqchart
4.google chart

i would prefer to use google chart. its easy to use and works really good.

Comment: Thanks, is the google chart has the functionality of drill down.